# Doc2Vec - Finding document similarity in test data

Tags: python, machine-learning, gensim, doc2vec

I am trying to train a doc2vec model using training data, then finding the similarity of every document in the **test data** for a specific document in the **test data** using the trained doc2vec model. However, I am unable to determine how to do this.

I currently using `model.docvecs.most_similar(...)`. However, this function only finds the similarity of every document in the **training data** for a specific document in the **test data**.

I have tried manually comparing the inferred vector of a specific document in the test data with the inferred vectors of every other document in the test data using `model.docvecs.n_similarity(inferred_vector.tolist(), testvectors[i].tolist())` but this returns `KeyError: "tag '-0.3502606451511383' not seen in training corpus/invalid"` as there are vectors not in the dictionary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The act of training-up a `Doc2Vec` model leaves it with a record of the doc-vectors learned from the training data, and yes, `most_similar()` just looks among those vectors.

Generally, doing any operations on new documents that weren't part of training will require the use of `infer_vector()`. Note that such inference:

- ignores any unknown words in the new document
- may benefit from parameter tuning, especially for short documents
- is currently done just one document at time in a single thread – so, acquiring inferred-vectors for a large batch of N-thousand docs can actually be slower than training a fresh model on the same N-thousand docs
- isn't necessarily deterministic, unless you take extra steps, because the underlying algorithms use random initialization and randomized selection processes during training/inference
- just gives you the vector, without loading it into any convenient storage-object for performing further `most_similar()`-like comparisons

On the other hand, such inference from a "frozen" model can be parallelized across processes or machines.

The `n_similarity()` method you mention isn't really appropriate for your needs: it's expecting lists of lookup-keys ('tags') for existing doc-vectors, *not* raw vectors like you're supplying.

The `similarity_unseen_docs()` method you mention in your answer is somewhat appropriate, but just takes a pair of docs, re-calculating their vectors each time – somewhat wasteful if a single new document's doc-vector needs to be compared against many other new documents' doc-vectors.

You may just want to train an all-new model, with both your "training documents" and your "test documents". Then all the "test documents" get their doc-vectors calculated, and stored inside the model, as part of the bulk training. This is an appropriate choice for many possible applications, and indeed could learn interesting relationships based on words that only appear in the "test docs" in a totally unsupervised way. And there's not yet any part of your question that gives reasons why it couldn't be considered here.

Alternatively, you'd want to `infer_vector()` all the new "test docs", and put them into a structure like the various `KeyedVectors` utility classes in `gensim` - remembering all the vectors in one array, remembering the mapping from doc-key to vector-index, and providing an efficient bulk `most_similar()` over the set of vectors.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer! The reason I don't just retrain with all the data including the test data is mainly because of speed and performance reasons with an app which can get new data in constant time. As for the last part of your answer? Do you mean manually inferring the vectors then merging them into an array so I can use them as the model? From my understanding, `KeyedVectors` is for `Word2Vec` functions only. Is that not true?

Comment: Well, depending on relative sizes of your 'training' and 'test' docs, & how much better the model could be if 'test' docs were included during initial training, & compute budget available, it still might be worth considering. As noted: bulk inference is (given current implementations) going to be slower than bulk training – & to the extent new docs might teach about new words & new patterns in the data, only a retrain will gather that. (A mixed approach could be: use inference for small groups of new docs as they arrive, but regularly re-build the base model as an occasional background job.)

Comment: The `Doc2Vec` model's `.docvecs` property is itself a kind of `KeyedVectors` (specifically `Doc2VecKeyedVectors`). The various classes in gensim's `keyedvectors.py` (https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim/blob/develop/gensim/models/keyedvectors.py) support similar operations for a bunch of uses in the word2vec-related-family of models. I find their current incarnations a bit weird/duplicative, but my point is there might be something in there you could use for holding your own incremental batches of inferred vectors – or use as a model/base for your own similarly-functioning code.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out there is a function called `similarity_unseen_docs(...)` which can be used to find the similarity of 2 documents in the **test data**.

However, I will leave the question unsolved for now as it is not very optimal since I would need manually compare the specific document with every other document in the **test data**. Also, it compares the words in the documents instead of the vectors which could affect accuracy.